# How to read from Tornado handler if that key, value pair exists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I am adding on client key, value pair to header request (in POST and GET request) like

```
'version', '2.2.9'
```

nad I want to check on server. How to read from Tornado handler if that key, value pair exists and what is value if exists ?

Comment: To check if this pair exists you can simply use `if self.request.headers.has_key("version")`; because `self.request.headers` is a dictionary. For checking the value, I refer you to @jcfaracco's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on Server side:

Your sample class...

```
class SampleController(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
```

And get the key,value doing...

```
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        version = self.request.headers.get('version')
        if version == '2.2.9':
            # your own code

    def post(self, **kwargs):
        version = self.request.headers.get('version')
        if version == '2.2.9':
            # your own code
```

You can test you server side application using a REST plugin/addon. Postman for chrome or RESTClient for firefox.